# C# Null Reference Exception - Object reference not set

Tags: c#

When this code gets called, I'm getting an error on

```
|| c.CustomerOrderNumber.Contains(query)
```

It runs ok if I comment out those two line in the code below.

```
public class PredispatchController : CommonController
{
    protected object SearchOrders(string query, string sort, int page, int take)
    {
        int totalRows = (from c in _stockEntities.spM80PreDispatch()
                         where c.OrderNumber.Contains(query)
                         || c.CustomerOrderNumber.Contains(query)
                         || c.DName.Contains(query)
                         || c.PartNo.Contains(query)
                         || c.StockDesc.Contains(query)
                         select c).Count();

        var results = (from c in _stockEntities.spM80PreDispatch()
                       where c.OrderNumber.Contains(query)
                       || c.CustomerOrderNumber.Contains(query)
                       || c.DName.Contains(query)
                       || c.PartNo.Contains(query)
                       || c.StockDesc.Contains(query)
                       select c).AsQueryable();

        int skip = 0;

        ViewData["pageLinks"] = Pagination.Paging("Search", page, totalRows, take, out skip);

        return AddSortQuery(sort, results).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
    }
```

The full error is this:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
>
> CELIntranet.Models.spM80PreDispatch_Result.CustomerOrderNumber.get returned null.

Am I to assume that it can't find the object called `CustomerOrderNumber` from the returned `spM80PreDispatch_Result`

or

is it because some of the records in the `CustomerOrderNumber` column has Null values?

I'm new to ASP.NET and C# and I am struggling with learning some of this stuff. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Ok so what it means is: c is not null, c.CustomerOrderNumber is null

Comment: some records have CustomerOrderNumber with a null value inside, use  || c?.CustomerOrderNumber?.Contains(query)

Comment: Why don't you debug the code and check whether `c.CustomerOrderNumber` is null?

Comment: Thanks for pointers. I tried to use ? solution but the compiler underlines it in red and says Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'bool?'

Comment: Experts, thank you for your help with this.  The solution for me was not the code in the C# controller but instead to add the IsNull function to the SQL stored procdure and set it to return a '?' where records had the 'NULL' in the column data.